# Asterisk 13 и CallerID

Tags: asterisk, sip

Настроен Asterisk 13.18.3 на Ubuntu Server 18.04 (из репозиториев).

sip.conf

```
[general]
externaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx        ; Внешний IP-адрес
language=ru                       ; Локализация звуков
context=default
allowguest=no                     ; Разрешить/Запретить гостевые подключения
alwaysauthreject=yes              ; Разрешить/Запретить отвечать на INVITE и REGISTER
allowoverlap=no                   ; Разрешить/Запретить набор по одной цифре
limitonpeers=yes                  ; Разрешить/Запретить лимит на кол-во одновременных разговоров
srvlookup=yes                     ; Принимать SIP вызовы на основании доменных имен
useragent=Asterisk JAKONDA        ; Значение поля useragent в SIP заголовке

; Блок регистраций транков
register=zadarma_login:zadarma_pass@sip.zadarma.com/7499xxxxxxx ; Тестовый номер

[authentication]

[internal_numbers](!)            ; Шаблон для ВНУТРЕННИХ НОМЕРОВ
type=friend                      ; peer(Исходящие) и user(Входящие) в одном
context=internal-calls           ; Контекст обработки входящих вызовов
host=dynamic
nat=no                           ; Политики работы через nat
qualify=yes                      ; Переодическая проверка доступности клиента
canreinvite=no                   ; Разрешить/Запретить потоки peer-to-peer в обход сервера
insecure=port,invite             ; port (не требовать совпадения порта), invite (не требовать аутентификации)
dtmfmode=rfc2833                 ; Какую спецификацию использовать при передачи DTMF сигналов
disallow=all                     ; Запретить использование всех кодеков, ниже разрешаем нужные
allow=alaw
allow=g729

[101](internal_numbers)
fromuser=101
secret=password

; Zadarma
[zadarma](!)
type=friend
host=sip.zadarma.com
qualify=yes
fromdomain=sip.zadarma.com
insecure=invite,port
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
allow=g729

; ============================== Транки =============================

[7499xxxxxxx](zadarma) ; Тестовый номер
username=zadarma_login
fromuser=zadarma_login
secret=zadarma_pass
context=test-calls
```

extensions.conf

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no

[globals]

[default]

[test-calls]
exten => 7499xxxxxxx,1,NoOp()
exten => 7499xxxxxxx,n,Answer()
exten => 7499xxxxxxx,n,Verbose(1,Звонок на линию "Тест" с номера ${CALLERID(num)})
exten => 7499xxxxxxx,n,Dial(SIP/101)
exten => 7499xxxxxxx,n,Hangup()
```

К Asterisk на номер 101 подключен 3CXPhone 6. При звонке на номер 7499xxxxxxx звонок приходит в софтфон, но отображается номер входящего 101. В консоли Asterisk всё отображается корректно: "Звонок на линию "Тест" с номера 7920xxxxxxx".

Как сделать так, чтобы номер в софтфне отображался корректно?

Comment: а если вместо 3CXPhone попробовать zoiper (например)? Что видно в `sngrep`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю конфигурацию, вы настроили подстановку вызывающего номера 101 при звонках на 101 и теперь хотите это дело обойти, не удаляя параметра `fromuser` из конфигурации 101-го экстеншена.

Попробуйте следующее:

1. Убрать Answer(). Он там очевидно лишний.
2. В sip.conf вместо `fromuser=101` написать `fromuser=<101>`. Это вроде по стандарту так (этот и предыдущий пункты не должны ничего изменить, они просто для корректности).
3. Поподставлять в `CALLERID(name)` значение из `CALLERID(num)` перед вызовом Dial().
4. Если ничего не помогает, то согласиться с тем, что вы сам так захотели, когда прописывали `fromuser`.

Comment: п. 4 помог. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
insecure=port,invite
```

удали из internal_numbers, этот параметр нельзя использовать с host=dynamic

P.S. Это не ответ на ваш вопрос, это совет по безопасности :)